# Dynamic array inside an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am not sure if question title is ok or not!

I am trying to dynamically input array inside an array.

This is how it should be:

Example array:

```
$myArray = array (
    'id' => 123,
    'name' => 'Sufi',
    'works' => array (
        'show_work' => TRUE,
        'number' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        /*i want this part to be dynamic */
        array (
            'title' => 'developer',
            'experience' => '5 years',
            'company' => 'ABC Inc.',
        ),
        array (
            'title' => 'CEO',
            'experience' => '1 year',
            'Company' => 'XYZ LLC.',
        ),
       /*i want this part to be dynamic */
    ),
);
```

This is what I have:

```
//this array contains all works
$works = array(
    array (
        'title' => 'developer',
        'experience' => '5 years',
        'company' => 'ABC Inc.',
    ),
    array (
        'title' => 'CEO',
        'experience' => '1 year',
        'Company' => 'XYZ LLC.',
    ),
);
```

Now how can I pass this to `$myArray` dynamically?

### My desired array format

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123
    [name] => sufi
    [works] => Array
        (
            [show_work] => TRUE
            [number] => -1
            [order] => DESC
            [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => developer
                [experience] => 5 years
                [company] => ABC Inc.
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => CEO
                [experience] => 1 year
                [company] => XYZ LLC.
            )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope I understood your question correctly:-

Try this:-

```
$myArray = array (
'id' => 123,
'name' => 'Sufi',
'works' => array (
    'show_work' => true,
    'number' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC'
   )
);

$works = array(
  array (
    'title' => 'developer',
    'experience' => '5 years',
    'company' => 'ABC Inc.',
  ),
 array (
    'title' => 'CEO',
    'experience' => '1 year',
    'Company' => 'XYZ LLC.',
   ),
 );

foreach ( $works as $work ) {
   $myArray ['works'][] = $work;
}
```

Final Array will be:-

```
$myArray = array (
'id' => 123,
'name' => 'Sufi',
'works' => array (
    'show_work' => TRUE,
    'number' => -1
    'order' => 'DESC',
    [0] => array (
        'title' => 'developer',
        'experience' => '5 years',
        'company' => 'ABC Inc.',
    ),
    [1] => array (
        'title' => 'CEO',
        'experience' => '1 year',
        'Company' => 'XYZ LLC.',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I have actually tried this. this makes structure like this: `array( array(), array() )`, inside `'works'`.
But I am looking for `array(), array()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have used it inside a foreach loop and it solved my problem. Kindly check my answer.

Comment: Please update your answer, so that I can select it as correct answer.

Comment: please check now :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to those nice people, who tried to help me. I have solved it based on idea from @Ashutosh.

This is the solution:

```
foreach ( $works as $work ) {
    $myArray ['works'][] = $work;
}
```

Comment: why there is a -1 for this one??